# React - how to access other elements in handleClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am iterating over an array, and for each element, I pass it to a `handleClick` function. The question is, **inside that handleClick function**, how do I access the rest of the elements?

```
const listOfAnswers = questions[questionNumber].possibleAnswers.map((obj, i, arr) => {
        return (
            <Button
                key={i}
                style={
                    {
                        margin: '15px 0',
                    }
                }
                variant='contained'
                onClick={e => handleClick(obj, e, arr)}
            >
                {obj.answer}
            </Button>
        )
    })
```

```
const handleClick = async (obj, e, arr) => {
        const { isCorrect, answer } = obj

        if (isCorrect) {
            setScore(score + 1)
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
            await delay(100)
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = ''
        } else {
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red'

            await delay(100)
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = ''
        }

        nextQuestion()

    }
```

What I am trying to do is: when  a user clicks on the right answer, that button turns green. This is straightforward to implement. When a user clicks the wrong answer, it turns red. Also simple to implement. But what I want is: when a user clicks on the wrong answer, I want the right answer to turn green. For this I think I need to be able to access the rest of the elements, because in the `handleClick` function, you only have access to a single, individual element.

Answer (score 0):

There are various way to do it:

1. Add a `answer` to the state (initialized to undefined). Your handleClick will set this state to the answer the user selected. Then if `answer` is defined, pass a green backgroundColor in the style of the correct button (next to your margin). And on the button whose `obj.answer === answer`, if obj.isCorrect is false, set a red backgroundColor. (note you would need to reset `answer` state to undefined in your `nextQuestion`)
2. Add a `ref` to the correct answer Button (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), and on handleClick, you can set `ref.current.style.background`.

###### UPDATE with example of ref

The following assumes that there is a unique correct answer (link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-swirles-7q6wz2?file=/src/App.js:0-2575):

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Quiz time!</h1>
      <Questions />
    </div>
  );
}

const Questions = () => {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [questionNumber, setQuestionNumber] = useState(0);
  const correctAnswerRef = useRef(null);

  // If all questions were answered we display the score
  if (questionNumber >= questions.length) {
    const reset = () => {
      setScore(0);
      setQuestionNumber(0);
    };
    return (
      <div>
        Score: {score} <Button onClick={reset}>Take the quiz again</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  const handleClick = async (obj, e) => {
    const { isCorrect } = obj;
    // always set current answer to green
    if (correctAnswerRef.current) {
      correctAnswerRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    if (isCorrect) {
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else {
      // if wrong answer was selected, put a red background
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    // just to simulate `delay` since I don't have that util
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "";
    if (correctAnswerRef.current) {
      correctAnswerRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }

    // too lazy to implement nextQuestion, so I just increment the question number
    setQuestionNumber(questionNumber + 1);
  };

  const question = questions[questionNumber];

  const listOfAnswers = question.possibleAnswers.map((obj) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          key={obj.answer} // ideally each answer should have one (and you should never use index!)
          ref={obj.isCorrect ? correctAnswerRef : undefined}
          style={{
            margin: "15px 0"
          }}
          variant="contained"
          onClick={(e) => handleClick(obj, e)}
        >
          {obj.answer}
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{question.question}</div>
      {listOfAnswers}
    </div>
  );
};

const questions = [
  {
    question: "Is this working?",
    possibleAnswers: [
      {
        answer: "Yes",
        isCorrect: true
      },
      {
        answer: "No",
        isCorrect: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "Is this a good question?",
    possibleAnswers: [
      {
        answer: "Nope",
        isCorrect: false
      },
      {
        answer: "Yes, it is!",
        isCorrect: true
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: I do feel like using a `ref` is the best approach here, but I dont know much about how to use a `ref`

Comment: @5ecured updated the answer with an example of how ref could be used. But in my opinion, the style/class based on state approach is more standard in React than manually modifying the style attribute on an event

Comment: I tried implementing your solutino, but it still does not work. Still, I appreciate your help

Comment: @5ecured So I tried a minimal repro on codesandbox and it seems to be working fine. I mainly fixed `correctAnswerRef.current?.style.backgroundColor = "green"` which was not working because optional chaining `?.` cannot be used for assignment. If you had as well, your problem might come from another part of your code you are not showing. Another change I made that shouldn't impact much in this case is that I did remove the key=index and replaced it by key=answer (Try to use unique identifiers for `key`, it should **never** be the index of the element => you could check react reconciliation).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(-1);

const listOfAnswers = questions[questionNumber].possibleAnswers.map((obj, i, arr) => {
    return (
        <Button
            key={i}
            style={
                {
                    margin: '15px 0',
                    color: clicked == -1
                      ? "#ffffff"
                      : clicked == i && obj.isCorrect
                      ? "#00ff00"
                      : cliked != i
                      ? "#ffffff"
                      : "#ff0000"
                }
            }
            variant='contained'
            onClick={e => handleClick(i)}
        >
            {obj.answer}
        </Button>
    )
})
const handleClick = async (i) => {
   setClicked(i)
   nextQuestion()
}
```

Comment: Do you use functional component or class component?

Comment: I tried this, but still doesnt work. I use functional component

Comment: how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(-1);

const listOfAnswers = questions[questionNumber].possibleAnswers.map((obj, i, arr) => {
    return (
        <Button
            key={i}
            style={
                {
                    margin: '15px 0',
                    color: clicked == -1
                      ? "#ffffff"
                      : clicked == i && obj.isCorrect
                      ? "#00ff00"
                      : cliked != i
                      ? "#ffffff"
                      : "#ff0000"
                }
            }
            variant='contained'
            onClick={handleClick}
        >
            {obj.answer}
        </Button>
    )
})
const handleClick = (e) => {
   setClicked(e.target.key)
}
```